# Read block of lines in text file

Tags: c#, loops, text-files, logfile

I am writing a program to read a log file. each entry starts with a time-stamp, except when there is an error, which in this case, I would have multiple lines for the error message and without time-stamp.

The file looks like this:

```
20190207 14:23:10.123 info Read input
20190207 14:23:11.001 info connecting to database
20190207 14:23:17.101 error truncating the table customer. Error code XXXX
the file was blocked.
```

I would like to store every entry with its time-stamp, event type, and message in a table that has three columns, one column for the time-stamp (datetime) and another column for the events (info/warning/error), and a column for the text (data type text).

How do I iterate through the file and read all the entries including the error message which sometimes be in multiple lines?

Comment: Could you show your code, please?

Comment: Could you describe the trouble you're having with your current approach? It should be relatively easy to tell if a line is a continuation of a previous line's error (i.e. It won't begin with a predictable timestamp - presumably).

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the events and the text?

Comment: the second column is the event (info, warning, error). in case of it is an error, it usually have multiple line, I would like to to store those multiple lines in one message with the event error and time stamp

Comment: the code is too long to fit in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use `Regex` to try to match each line of the log. If you have match then you create entry otherwise you append the line to the existing entry. I will provide the code to try to explain approach...

```
//strings for simplification, in your code you should use DateTime and parse properly
public class Entry
{
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could define `regular expression` to capture log line. I did this using groups so it is easier to extract data from it. Notice that you should add all types you expect, I just use `info|error|warning`.

```
//you should define all types you expect in log, I just put info and error
string LogLineRegex = @"(?<date>\d{4}\d{2}\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}) (?<type>info|error|warning) (?<text>.*)";
```

And then read each line of the log:

- **match** - create new entry
- **not match** - append the line to the rolling entry, assumption is that you have an error

Log parsing example

```
Entry rollingEntry = null;

foreach (var line in log)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(line, LogLineRegex);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        if (rollingEntry != null) { entries.Add(rollingEntry); }

        rollingEntry = new Entry{ 
            Timestamp = match.Groups["date"].ToString(),
            Type = match.Groups["type"].ToString(),
            Description = match.Groups["text"].ToString() };
    }
    else
    {
        if (rollingEntry != null) { rollingEntry.Description += $"{Environment.NewLine}{line}"; }
    }
}
```